# How to create grid view for the Custom List

Tags: gridview

How to create a grid view for the custom list, It would be better if someone explain, how it can be implemented through JavaScript or Jquery using webpart.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by grid view? And how do you want it to be different from Datasheet view? And what version of Sharepont are you asking about?

Comment: I don't know but my quick edit is not working with datasheet view and I want to use gridview which I can edit and ya if possible I want to apply color too.